# Emacs fails to evaluate .emacs file under Windows

Tags: windows, emacs

I have following simple .emacs

```
(require 'package)
(push '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/") package-archives )
(push '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") package-archives)

;; enable evil aka vim-bindings
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)

;; enable workgroups
(require 'workgroups2)
(workgroups-mode 1)

(require 'tramp)
(setq tramp-default-method "plink")
```

When I start emacs I get following:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `e:/home/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, evil
```

When I try to evalute s-expressions separately they work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you probably have to install `evil` first. Adding the repositories is not enough. You can install packages by typing <kbd>M-x</kbd>`list-packages`, this will take you to the list of avaiable packages on your current repositories (in that case *marmalade* and *melpa*), just find `evil` and them press enter to be prompted with installation options.

If you want to do that by code, you can use the `package-install` function, like this:

```
(package-refresh-contents) 
(package-install 'evil)
```

I use [a function written by this user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10095853/1335511) from StackOverflow, which enables me to specify a list of packages to be installed at my emacs startup. You should take a look.

Comment: yes, this was the issue. I had installed evil, but managed to wipe it out.